# Need help retreiving 2 ETH from my metamask to my safe (Gnosis) arbitrum account

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core

I sent by mistake 2 ETH (Ethereum network) from my metamask to my Safe Arbitrum address. https://etherscan.io/address/0x7063c2ea84c4fea13e9d7f7668828ef6abee531d
How can I retreive the funds?
My metamask ETH account is 0x989c4FB381b38fd031862F96a8519ac438552EA3
My arbitrum safe account is (arb1:) 0x7063c2EA84c4fEa13e9D7F7668828Ef6AbeE531d
The Help support at safe told me its possible and to ask here.
I would really appreciate anyone that can go with me step by step on how to do that.
I am ready to pay you for your time.
Thank you,
Jean

Answer (score 0):

We will need to deploy a new Safe on Ethereum, at the exact same address than your Arbitrum address. The new Safe on Ethereum will have the same paramaters as your Safe on Arbitrum, so you should be able to recover your ETH using the same thresholds and owners addresses as the one on Arbitrum.

You can find step-by-step explanations on how to do this in [this video](https://www.loom.com/share/ca34aabcd62747fb9fb89bd463b4c741), as well as in [this guide](https://help.safe.global/en/articles/40812-i-sent-assets-to-a-safe-address-on-the-wrong-network-any-chance-to-recover). Please follow each step carefully and contact support again on help.safe.global if you encounter any problem in the process.

Hope it helps! Louis